# Saving data to Firebase Realtime Database - Swift İOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to save a dictionary to Firebase Database with the code at the most below. Fairly simple code which only should write something like:

```
Genre
  fileName:
     user
  fileName2:
     user2
  fileName3:
     user3
  fileName4:
     user4
```

so on... So it basically is an array of file names which consists of user values. But it keeps giving me an error as below.

> (setValue:) Invalid key in object at path: . Keys must be non-empty and cannot contain '/' '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

You can see my code as below:
I'm trying to set a value as [fileName: username] which is an array of dictionaries, then set them under the child of "Genre". Why this error happens? And how can I solve it?

Thanks.

```
public func insertPostsToDB(with fileName: String, user: String, genre: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        
        guard let username = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "username") else {
            
            return
        }

        database.child("\(genre)").setValue([fileName : username]) 
}
```

Comment: Remove \ from .child and use it like  database.child("genre").setValue...

Comment: The error is suggesting that either your file name or user name is empty. Have you printed or used the debugger to make sure that they have values (besides `""`)?

Comment: I got the value for filename and genre

Comment: the values are fileName: 1628150362.236193F37E7016-0F8B-4474-BAF2-AC9560F1624B_895_.mov, 
genre : Rock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have disallowed characters in your `genre` variable. I recommend to print that value, and see if it contains one of the characters mentioned in the error message.

If so, you won't be able to use the genre as a key without encoding those disallowed characters into ones that are allowed.

Comment: Hi Frank. I do get the value for "genre", as a String even non optional. And it doesn't contain any restricted characters. Still getting the same error

Comment: Besides that the values that I'm getting are fileName: 1628150362.236193F37E7016-0F8B-4474-BAF2-AC9560F1624B_895_.mov, Genre: Rock.
What am I missing

Comment: I've never seen that error message fire in vain, so I recommend looking further into your code exactly where the error occurs and what value each variable has that you're using in there.

Comment: Thanks Frank! The problem was trying to save the data under the name fileName which consists "." . After removing the dot in the filename, it worked perfectly to save to database. Accepted your answer as the solution. Have a great day